# No valid bootloader target device found(For UEFI installation)

Tags: windows, boot, bios, fedora, uefi

I have `windows 10` and `fedora 20` in my laptop(Dual boot). I wanna install `fedora 24`(by replace it on existing fedora),I made bootable usb disk from `fedora 24` iso file with `LiveUSB Creator`, but during the installation,  when I end my partitioning and mounting (eg /home, /boot and etc), I get this error:

```
No valid bootloader target device found. 
For UEFI installation , you must include an EFI System Partition on a 
GPT-formatted disk, mounted at /boot/efi.
```

My BIOS is `legacy` mode and it cannot be changed to `UEFI` mode(also for booting from usb, the usb is booted only in legacy mode). I installed `fedora` 20 years ago but now I can't install `fedora` 24 for this issue. I googled many hours and I tried many solutions, but still my problem is not solved, I am very tired now, Pls help me, tnx.

Comment: It sounds like you booted the USB drive in UEFI mode though. If it's not the case, it could be a bug of the installer.

Comment: @TomYan Yeah, and I can't change it to legacy mode, because my bios doesn't supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem with reinstall `fedora 24` with DVD disk(not USB), because always my USB is booted in `UEFI mode` and I couldn't to change it to `lagacy/BIOS mode`(for my BIOS). In this case, when DVD is booted, the BIOS let me to choose a mode from `UEFI mode` and `BIOS mode`, I chose `BIOS mode` and installed it.

Comment: Yes, pressing F8 have 2 options to select from, one the UEFI and another normal. We can do the same without DVD.

Answer (score -2):

In the bootloader options I selected the `Legacy USB mode` and not `UEFI`. Start the install process again and it works.